# JQuery click to continuously add new element

Tags: jquery, click

I have some code that makes a `<p>` element appear when a button is clicked using jquery.  If the button is pressed twice I would like for another `<p>` element to appear.  Right now that doesn't happen (the `<p>` only appears once).

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function() {
        $(".input").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<p class='input' style='display: none;'>
    text here
</p>

<input type='button' value='Add class' id='add'>
```

Comment: That's because it only shows a hidden element, it does not create a new one.

Comment: @asawyer how can i create a new one?

Comment: Do you want to add an entirely new empty p tag or are you wishing to reveal an additional p tag that was previously hidden like your current script does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one hidden `p` with class of `input` you can try:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:hidden:first").show()
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3PXhn/)

Comment: this solution only works for 3 `<p>` tags.  I need it to work for an infinite amount.  All of the p tags can have the same contents.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `<p>` element dynamically. Something like:

```
$('#add').before($('<p>').addClass('input').text('text here'));
```

Or, if you have a more complicated template than that, you may want to clone the element:

```
var lastItem = $('.input').eq(-1);
lastItem.after(lastItem.clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `append` method to add p tags to a div or the body.  HTML:

```
<div id="pTags"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#pTags").append('<p>text</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're showing a hidden element, not creating a new one. Use this instead:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("<p class='input'></p>").appendTo("body");
});
```